# react-map-gl without API key using osm tiles

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap, react-map-gl

Is it possible?

[This](http://bl.ocks.org/AlanPew/5acf9fca0) tells me it is, but dont know why it defines and API key.

but I cannot get it to work with `react-map-gl` StaticMap class. The property I can see from that class is just `mapStyle` which would take a standard Mapbox vector tiles path/name. Does it take an object? My code does not give me an error or show the tiles I request.

```
    <DeckGL>
        <StaticMap
            mapStyle= {{
                "version": 7,
                "sources": {
                  "simple-tiles": {
                    "type": "raster",
                    "tiles":["http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", "http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"],
                    "tileSize": 256
                  },
                  "power": {
                  "type": "vector",
                  "tiles": ["http://gpstrails.info/ex/leaflet/power/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.json"]
                }
                },
                "layers": [{
                  "id": "simple-tiles",
                  "type": "raster",
                  "source": "simple-tiles",
                  "minzoom": 0,
                  "maxzoom": 22
                },
                {
                "id": "road",
                "source": "power",
                "source-layer": "power",
                "type": "line",
                "layout": {
                  "line-join": "round",
                  "line-cap": "round",
                },
                "paint": {
                  "line-color": "red",
                  "line-width": 4,
                }
              }]
              }}/>
    </DeckGL>
```

Thank you

Edit: from the correct answer, and to keep things in SO, this is the `json` living on the S3:

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "name": "OSM",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "sources": {
    "openmaptiles": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "https://free.tilehosting.com/data/v3.json?key={key}"
    },
    "osm": {
      "type": "raster",
      "tiles": [
        "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      ],
      "minzoom": 0,
      "maxzoom": 14
    },
    "91y5159eg": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/tilejson.json"
    }
  },
  "sprite": "https://openmaptiles.github.io/klokantech-basic-gl-style/sprite",
  "glyphs": "https://free.tilehosting.com/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf?key=undefined",
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "osm",
      "type": "raster",
      "source": "osm"
    }
  ],
  "id": "klokantech-basic"
}
```

**UPDATE:** Mapbox [changed](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#200) their license in 2.0 so the accepted answer is correct for versions < 2.0. Mapbox > 2.0 will complain if no access_token is provided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is in the style that's used. A style is a JSON object, whose specification you can read more about [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/). You can generate custom styles using tools such as [Maputnik](https://maputnik.github.io/), a visual editor that generates style-compliant files for use in MapboxGL maps. Once you have an appropriate style generated, you can use it in React Map GL.

Here's what the basic component would look like, as altered from the example in the [Github repo](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl):

```js
<ReactMapGL
        mapStyle="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.brianbancroft.io/assets/osmstyle.json"
        {...this.state.viewport}
        onViewportChange={viewport => this.setState({ viewport })}
      />
```

Note that this is just an abstract example. The tile loads from OSM here are a bit too slow to be useful in production. But it should illustrate how to make maps without relying on the services side of Mapbox.

Comment: Fantastic. See if I can add a standalone example to some JS code space.